# Partitions on clean install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I have a 500GB harddrive with 2 operating systems installed: Windows 7 (120GB) and Ubuntu 13.04 (380GB). I created my own partitions, by using advice from this [tutorial](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/). Now I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and install Windows 7 in a virtual machine of 100GB.

Here are my questions:

1. Since I will no longer have a dual-boot, how do I create my partitions such that they use my entire harddrive? Or is it better to use the default ones that the installer creates? If yes, on which partition will my virtual machine be?
2. When I make a clean install of Ubuntu will it erase my Windows partitions?

This is my current configuration, the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           465.8G            
├─sda1 ntfs     100M            System Reserved
├─sda2 ntfs    19.4G            
├─sda3 ntfs    97.7G            
├─sda4            1K            
├─sda5 ext4     953M /boot      
├─sda6 ext4    37.3G /          
├─sda7 swap     4.7G [SWAP]     
└─sda8 ext4   305.7G /home      
sr0            1024M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulation to getting rid of dual boot, that is a vice decision.

> Since I will no longer have a dual-boot, how do I create my partitions such that they use my entire harddrive?

Ubuntu installation allows you to use your whole hardrive and it will erase it fully and create partitions for you. If you decided to do so you can also manually alter the partitions.

> Or is it better to use the default ones that the installer creates?

As a user of Linux for 15 years, I realized that playing with partitions creates more hassle than it solves, so I would go with default ones.

> If yes, on which partition will my virtual machine be?

default partitions for ubuntu Desktop is only one big partition for root and one swap partition. Than it will be obviously in the root partition.

> When I make a clean install of Ubuntu will it erase my Windows partitions?

if you let Ubuntu to use whole your hardrive, it will erase all your Windows partitions! (please do your backup)

Additionally you should be aware:

1. if you have OEM version of Windows 7 which is tight to your BIOS, it will be difficult to get it properly registered under VirtualBox. Especially Dell laptops are well known for this.
2. Remember to verify that your backups actually works!

Comment: Thank you for your response! My version of Windows did not come with the laptop, so I won't have any problems. I will definitely backup before installing the new Ubuntu version.